# SearchView не обрабатывает поиск по пустой строке

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

Использую для поиска в приложении `onQueryTextListener`.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Делаем что-то...
                return true;
            }
```

Если набрать на клавиатуре устройства какую-нибудь фразу, всё нормально. Но, если всё стереть и нажать кнопку поиска на клавиатуре, не происходит ничего. Отладчик даже в событие не заходит.

В чём секрет и как решить эту проблему? Ведь по логике при поиске по пустой строке, результаты поиска должны сбрасываться.

Comment: `Ведь по логике при поиске по пустой строке, результаты поиска должны сбрасываться` откуда такая логика? Попробуйте в google что то поискать, и потом очистить строку поиска и снова поискать. По логике - пустая строка поиска не является запросом на поиск чего либо, потому новый поиск и не выполняется.

Comment: @tym32167, оттуда, что в приложениях, зачастую, строка поиска используется для фильтрации списка (или "поиска в списке" по-другому). Если мы ищем в списке товаров телефон, то видим телефоны, а когда очищаем строку поиска, то должны видеть все товары (по логике).